# A repository was not found at the specified path

Tags: svn, review-board

I have an SVN repository which has a certificate for authentication. When I try to add this SVN repository to the review board server, I am getting an error like "A repository was not found at the specified path.". Can anyone tell why am I getting this error and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by the ReviewBoard user not having permissions to read and execute the directory containing your repo. Check the user permissions and try again.